# How to get Full Plan in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I'm still a novice in SQL, and I would really appreciate it if you could help me.
How do I get SQL Plan for my query?  I have used this for getting a short plan:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
  FROM custinfo@smartdev2 s_cs
 WHERE s_cs.idcust = (SELECT b_cust_id
                        FROM mlb_test.mt_operation_out
                       WHERE id = 1230);

SELECT plan_table_output
  FROM TABLE (DBMS_XPLAN.display ('plan_table', NULL, 'basic'));
```

But what do i need to use for me to get entire execution plan?

- Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
  Version 18.3.0.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, the `'basic'` format will only display minimal information. Other formats include 'TYPICAL', 'SERIAL', 'ALL', and (undocumented) 'ADVANCED'. From the documentation for [`DBMS_XPLAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html#GUID-0EE333AF-E9AC-40A4-87D5-F6CF59D6C47B) it accepts four values:

> BASIC: Displays the minimum information in the plan—the operation ID,
> the operation name and its option.
>
> TYPICAL: This is the default. Displays the most relevant information
> in the plan (operation id, name and option, #rows, #bytes and
> optimizer cost). Pruning, parallel and predicate information are only
> displayed when applicable. Excludes only PROJECTION, ALIAS and REMOTE
> SQL information (see below).
>
> SERIAL: Like TYPICAL except that the parallel information is not
> displayed, even if the plan executes in parallel.
>
> ALL: Maximum user level. Includes information displayed with the
> TYPICAL level with additional information (PROJECTION, ALIAS and
> information about REMOTE SQL if the operation is distributed).

```
SELECT plan_table_output
  FROM TABLE (DBMS_XPLAN.display ('PLAN_TABLE', NULL, 'ALL'));
```

Check out this white paper from Oracle for additional details:

- [The Oracle Optimizer: Explain the Explain Plan](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/oracle-explain-the-explain-0218-4403741.pdf)